# PHP OOP: Missing argument from construct

Tags: php, class, constructor

The following notice and warning occurs after `var_dump` has excecuted correctly; i.e. `var_dump($params)` works, but these errors occur thereafter.

I found that using `public function __construct($params='')` in `Models_Index` class will cause ommition of these errors from occuring, but I'm not sure why they occur, or why this helps.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Models_Index::__construct()
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: params in models_index class on line 7

```
class Router {
  public function __construct(){
    $cont = new Controller('Passing params');
  }
} 
new Router;

class Controller extends Core_Controller {
  public function __construct($params) {  
    $model = $this->model("Models_Index", $params);
  }
}

class Core_Controller {
  protected function model($model, $params) {
    $model = new Models_Index($params);
    return new $model;
  }
}

class Models_Index extends Core_Model {
  public function __construct($params) {
    var_dump($params); // line 7
  }
}
```

Comment: your Controller class has no constructor, so exactly what are you expecting PHP to do with the `$params` you're trying to pass into it with `new Controller($params)`?

Comment: Is `$params` a value when it is sent to the `Models_Index` constructor?

Comment: @MarcB, yes it does.

Comment: @jack: woops. sorry. going cross-eyed here.

Comment: @MarcB No worries, haha.

Comment: @JackTuck : where is `Core_Model` defined in the code?

Comment: I left that out, doesn't seem relevent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you return `new $model`:

```
return new $model;
```

.. which is equal to

```
return new Models_Index();
```

Comment: Not quite, it would be equal to: `new Models_Index($params)`, so i was returning `new new Models_Index($params)` - which caused the error. You put me on the right track though, so +1.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, but I figuered it didnt make sense.

Comment: Actually, @msfoster is correct that it equals `new Models_Index()`.   If it were triggering `new Models_Index($params)`, you would just be seeing the output twice without errors.  This is why it warns a parameter is missing.